# select last added list item in combo box

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

iam using combobox, not bounded to data source in c#.

```
cmbBox.Items.Add("apple");
cmbBox.Items.Add("orange");
cmbBox.Items.Add("banana");
```

Now I want to set SelectedIndex to finally added "banana", but cannot use
    cmbBox.SelectedIndex = cmbBox.Items.count -1;
as the combo box is sorted !

Any tips please ?

Comment: @jeremy i used to use NewIndex in vb and was searching similar to it. I tried all expressions of indexof, selectedindex, selecteditem, combinations of them, and finally lost all direction/logic. Sorry, i didnot fill up this question with big story of struggle i had to find an answer and what i did/didn't do.

Answer (score 7):

Well i figured it out after refering the documentation. All tha i should have done is captured return value of cmbBox.Items.Add("something") statement and set it as cmbBox.SelectedIndex

```
nReturn = cmbBox.Items.Add("first");
...
nReturn = cmbBox.Items.Add("last");
cmbBox.SelectedIndex = nReturn;
```

Hope this helps some one.

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me

```
ComboBox cb = new ComboBox();
cb.Sorted = true;
cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Add("apple");
cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Add("orange");
cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Add("banana");
```

After the last line selected `index = 1` and `selected item = banana`

Comment: you are close to answer though setting selectedindex for each item when added is not necessary and additional load. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's quiet easy. Just use this...

cb.SelectedIndex = cb.Items.Count - 1;

Comment: This cannot be an answer of thia question. Please read carefully. OP said that case.

Answer (score 0):

It is even more simple than that. The index to the list in your case is "2" because the list is zero based and you added 3 items. So, count the number of items added to your list and subtract 1.  3 items, minus 1 = 2. Your last item added has a selectedindex of 2.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! OP states in his question, that he cannot use count - 1 technique as the combo box he's using is sorted, so the indices of the elements can change.

Comment: When your 76 years old, you sometimes miss the finer details. I should have read the question a little closer.  :)